# swfobject.embedSWF: 'onYouTubePlayerReady' and 'callbackFn' - What is the difference?

Tags: javascript, swfobject

I am using swfobject.js version 2.2.

I am calling swfobject.embedSWF with the last parameter (callbackFn) set to a local function in my Javascript code.

After that, two different routines are invoked:
1. My callback function
2. 'onYouTubePlayerReady', which is a callback function defined by the swfobject API.

What is the difference between these two, and on which one should I rely in order to be sure that the video has uploaded and is ready to play?

I am asking this, because on Safari, only my callback function is invoked, and so I need to know whether it is safe to rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

`onYouTubePlayerReady` is not a SWFObject method, it is an independent method supplied by YouTube's player API.

Your issue probably comes down to timing -- since `onYouTubePlayerReady` is part of the YouTube player API, it will not be available until the SWF has finished loading and ExternalInterface has been initialized by Flash Player.

SWFObject's `callbackFn` simply executes when the `<object>` has been successfully added to the page's markup, and does *not* indicate the SWF has loaded. In fact, SWFObject does not pay attention to whether the SWF loads at all.

However with a little bit of extra JavaScript you can poll the SWF to detect whether it has finished loading, then execute your custom script (in this case `onYouTubePlayerReady`).

This [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710799/load-timer-on-swfobject-for-swf-load-time) discusses the polling, and here's [a short tutorial explaining how to poll after embedding a SWF via SWFObject](http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/executing-javascript-when-the-swf-has-finished-loading/).