# swfobject 2.2 loader for swf

Tags: loader, swfobject

Embedding swf with swfobject 2.2, I need loader for swf file and want callback on swf loads 100%. I am currently using swfobject's percentLoaded method as I found answer [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7719671/970467)

But the problem is mozilla is giving me error of **too much recursion** and stops further execution.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a swf lader as a shell to load the child swif? So you dont need to include any JS in the process?

Comment: There were many problems already we faced in swf inside swf and this was the main reason we moved to swfobject, any other solutions please..